# Godaddy hosted domain vs paid domain

Tags: hosting, godaddy, domains

This is probably going to get downvoted into oblivion, but here it goes.  The company I work for has a deluxe hosting plan on Godaddy.  They have a hand full of domains registered under the same hosting account (for different product lines).  When I expand the "domains" tab, I can see only these few domains.  However under the hosing tab there is "9 Hosted domains"  Many of which I recognize as belonging to my boss' brother for his company.

All of the domains work perfectly fine.

I found this artice from godaddy : https://ca.godaddy.com/help/add-domains-8342

So, am I to understand that I can just add domains as I please for free? And if so, why would anyone bother paying for a second or third domain?  Is there some fundamental difference between a "hosted domain" and one I would have to pay for yearly?

Answer (score 2):

You can ADD them to the hosting configuration. Unless you pay for them that is just a piece of junk configuration in the host. Did you bother reading the link you sent to the end? IN the "What's next" section it is quite clear that the domain does not magically get registered for free.

Adding the domain to the domains in your hosting account does not make it a registered domain - which has to be done separately and is paid for all relevant domain types.

Comment: I did read it.  It says "We automatically update the domain name's DNS. You don't need to do anything!"  So why is it when I navigate to one of those other domains, they work fine? Neither can I find billing history for them.

Comment: never mind, I ran a whois on those other domains to find they are hosted elsewhere.  Makes sense now, thanks.